# Are the Linux kernel's stable git branches merged back into master?

Tags: git, linux-kernel, branching-and-merging

My understanding is that in the Linux kernel bug fixes are cherry-picked from the master branch into the stable branches (i.e. to backport a bugfix). Are those branches then merged back into master again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not, They wouldn't contribute anything new to master anyway would they?

You can check yourself

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
git remote add stable git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
git fetch stable
gitk -n 50000 stable/linux-3.11.y stable/linux-3.10.y master
```

Navigating single commits is too tedious, but using the "Follows" hyperlinks you can get reasonably easily down to e.g. 3.10 and then using "Precedes" up the 3.10.12 again (For 3.11 it's and its stable branch it's even shorter). You'll see the that stable branches involve no merging in either direction.

Should you get lost use history buttons (arrows) right of the SHA1 field to get back where you came from.

Comment: I was thinking that by merging back it would be easier to keep track of which commits you've already picked from master (when the next stable release comes along). In my project I have trouble keeping track of what has already been cherry-picked, as the commit hashes change.

Comment: @tibbe In the Linux kernel stable branches they always have the original SHA1 in the commit message. I'm not aware that git commands could do anything with them (besides gitk presenting them as a hyperlink). But you could easily search for an original SHA1 in you maintenance branch like this: git log  v3.11..v3.11.1 | grep -C 6 42dceeb